# 'KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain defintion for KeyCode error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a key press event in visual studio windows forms, but getting this error. Any ideas?

```
 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {  
            if (e.KeyCode = Keys.E)
            {
              // The Code when key 'E' is pressed
            }

        }
```

I keep getting  the error CS1061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyPressEventArgs objects has only a definition for KeyChar, which type is char, if you want to easy compare that char with any value defined on Keys class you can rewrite that conditional like this:

```
if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.E)
{
    // The Code when key 'E' is pressed
}
```

I hope it helps, and remember to use == in order to compare XD

Answer (score 1):

Im trying to make a key press event in visual studio windows forms but getting this error:

> The error CS1061

This error is because `KeyPressEventArgs` doesn't contain a definition for `KeyCode`, please see Microsoft [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) for more details on this compiler error. If you want to get the `KeyCode` one way you can get it with a combination of [KeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.8) event and using [KeyEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?view=netframework-4.8).

On another note, in your provided code you have `if (e.KeyCode = Keys.E)` that line should give you an error of some sort along the lines of:

> CS0200    Property or indexer ... cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

**To fix this**, you need to add two `==` so you can perform a equality check, not trying to assign.

**Solution:**

To fix your main issue, please see below the new signature you can use.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work sadly. Getting CS1061. Windgates solution did work tho

Comment: @JackW what do you mean doesn't work, getting CS1061?

Comment: Oh I see it needed to be KeyEventArgs not KeyPressEventArgs. I guess either would work.

Comment: @JackW yes, either is fine in your case. A note about the accepted solution. Not all keys will map correctly, so the comparison from `KeyChar` to `Keys' enum (cast) could fail.